# Poor image quality after bmp compression to jpg

Tags: android, android-camera, jpeg, bmp

I am working on a selftimer-photo-app.
Everything works quite good, but the finaly saved images have poor quality.
Original pictures are ~3MB in size, and the compressed pictures about 500kb.
The reason why I am using the bmp compression is the rotation of the picture.
I couldnt find an other solution for getting the rotation right.

Someone got an idea how to get better quality with working rotation?

this is my code:

```
camera = Camera.open();
camera.setDisplayOrientation(orient);
Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
params.setJpegQuality(100);
params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
camera.setParameters(params);
camera.takePicture(null,null, myPictureCallback_RAW);
```

Callback:

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] rawData, Camera arg1) {
 Matrix m = new Matrix();

 if(rotation == 3){
     m.postRotate(180);
 }else if(rotation == 1){
     m.postRotate(0);
 }else{
     m.postRotate(90);
 }

 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(rawData, 0, rawData.length);
 bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), m, true);

 Uri uriTarget = getContentResolver().insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new ContentValues());
 OutputStream imageFileOS;

 try {
  imageFileOS = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uriTarget);
  bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, imageFileOS);
  imageFileOS.close();
  Toast.makeText(CameraSnapshotActivity.this,

    "Image saved: " + uriTarget.toString(),

    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
 camera.startPreview();
 finish();
}
```

Comment: Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG change this to Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG it might help

Comment: @IllegalArgument , unfortunately same result :(

Comment: Can you show an image before and after rotation? Have you run some kind of JPEG dump program on the output to take a look at the quantization values?

Answer (score 1):

You can set JPEG rotation via Exif header without decoding it. This is the most efficient method, but some viewers may still show a rotated image.

Alternatively, you can use [JPEG lossless rotation](http://www.betterjpeg.com/lossless-rotation.htm). On SourceForge, there is a Java open source class [LLJTran](http://mediachest.sourceforge.net/mediautil/javadocs/mediautil/image/jpeg/LLJTran.html). The Android port is on [GitHub](http://github.com/bkhall/AndroidMediaUtil).